# Aspect in present simple tense

Tags: grammar

> He cleans his house by himself.

> He loves Chinese foods.

What aspect do these show in present simple tense?

My answer: Both show progressive aspect.

Comment: Can you claritfy your question? What do you want to know?

Comment: Aspect of present simple in general.

Comment: The "progressive aspect" of #1 is *He **is cleaning** his house by himself*. The corresponding construction for #2 *He **is loving** Chinese food* is only acceptable in "Indian English" - mainstream Anglophones don't use the progressive with "STATIVE" verbs like ***to love***.

Comment: ...unless they're [Justin Timberlake](https://www.macmillandictionaryblog.com/lovin-it).

Comment: Present simple doesn't have an aspect. Questions around here are becoming progressively worse. [sigh]

Comment: In one analysis, 'He cleans his house by himself.'  would be considered to exemplify the _habitual aspect_ [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitual_aspect)] and 'He loves Chinese foods' as _durative_.

Answer (score 1):

The aspects in English are "neutral", "progressive", "perfect" and "perfect-progressive".  The simple tenses are neutral in aspect. Your two examples are simple present, and so neutral in aspect.

Comment: Hello, James. I don't know when (or why) this was migrated to ELL from ELU, or the ELL stance on this, but ELU prefers answers backed by authoritative references. Would that be possible here, please?

Comment: See Time and the Verb
A Guide to Tense and Aspect
By Robert I. Binnick,

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Indeed, "why" is a good question. Before reading James' answer, "progressive" was the only aspect I could name, and I'm a native speaker, an experienced ESL teacher and a grammar nerd. IMO it was sent here in error. I'd send this question back, but then it'll get closed.

Comment: @gotube CGEL (Huddleston & Pullum) seems only to consider 'progressive' and 'non-progressive' (with a nod to starts and finishes) under 'aspect'.